# How to get environment variable value from .env file in Dockerfile shell script?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

How can I access environment variables defined in .env file in shell script?

.env file

```
USERNAME=user
PASSWORD=pass
```

Dockerfile

```
....

COPY ./compose/django/celery/worker/start_celery_flower.sh /start_celery_flower.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start_celery_flower.sh
RUN chmod +x /start_celery_flower.sh

....
```

I tried using `$USERNAME` in shell script, but that is not working. I am able to access these variables in application running inside container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
docker build $(cat .env | xargs -n1 echo '--build-arg' | tr '\n' ' ') .
```

And in your `Dockerfile` add

```
ARG USERNAME
ARG PASSWORD
```

Basically you need to past build args using --build-arg. The command i posted will help in getting multiple ones from a file .

**Edit-1**

To use in docker-compose use like below

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - USERNAME=$USERNAME
        - PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
```

Now you need to export the variables before sending to docker-compose

```
set -a
source .env
set +a
docker-compose up --build -d
```

Comment: How can I use it with docker-compose? I'm using compose file.

Comment: @AshishGupta, please mark this as the accepted answer, since this is the best way to accomplish this.